# How do I specify a default command-line argument for a different (Python) script via a shell script?

Tags: shell, command-line, environment-variables, command-line-arguments

My understanding of shell is very minimal, I'm working on a small task and need some help.

I've been given a python script that can parse command line arguments. One of these arguments is called "-targetdir". When -targetdir is unspecified, it defaults to a /tmp/{USER} folder on the user's machine. I need to direct -targetdir to a specific filepath.

I effectively want to do something like this in my script:

set ${-targetdir, "filepath"}

So that the python script doesn't set a default value. Would anyone know how to do this? I also am not sure if I'm giving sufficient information, so please let me know if I'm being ambiguous.

Comment: It's not clear what you expect the `set` syntax to actually *do* (it *doesn't* change the values of regular shell variables in bash). If you want to parse an argument to your script into a variable, that we have some existing Q&A entries w/ best practices for...

Comment: ...see [BashFAQ #35](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035) for some examples; the first big code chunk there accepts `--files` to set a variable `file`, `-v` to change a variable `verbose`, etc.

Comment: ...that said, I wonder if maybe what you want to do is *wrap* the Python script with a shell function or script that adds a `-targetdir` argument if there isn't already one given? That's doable, and I don't know without searching if it's already in the knowledgebase or not.

Comment: BTW, if your Python program *did* take a `targetdir` from the environment (as the tagging on the question implies) rather than falling back to `/tmp` in the absence of an explicit flag, this question would be moot: You could just `export targetdir=filepath`, and then rely on the Python code to look for `os.environ['targetdir']`.

Answer (score 1):

**I *strongly* suggest modifying the Python script to explicitly specify the desired default rather than engaging in this kind of hackery.**

That said, some approaches:

---

#### Option A: Function Wrapper

Assuming that your Python script is called `foobar`, you can write a wrapper function like the following:

```
foobar() {
  local arg found=0
  for arg; do
    [[ $arg = -targetdir ]] && { found=1; break; }
  done
  if (( found )); then
    # call the real foobar command without any changes to its argument list
    command foobar "$@"
  else
    # call the real foobar, with ''-targetdir filepath'' added to its argument list
    command foobar -targetdir "filepath" "$@"
  fi
}
```

If put in a user's `.bashrc`, any invocation of `foobar` from the user's interactive shell (assuming they're using bash) will be replaced with the above wrapper. Note that this doesn't impact other shells; `export -f foobar` will cause other instances of bash to honor the wrapper, but that isn't guaranteed to extend to instances of `sh`, as used by `system()` invocations, Python's `Popen(..., shell=True)`, and other places in the system.

---

#### Option B: Shell Wrapper

Assume you rename the original `foobar` script to `foobar.real`. Then you can make `foobar` a wrapper, like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
found=0
for arg; do
  [[ $arg = -targetdir ]] && { found=1; break; }
done
if (( found )); then
  exec foobar.real "$@"
else
  exec foobar.real -targetdir "filepath" "$@"
fi
```

Using `exec` terminates the wrapper's execution, replacing it with `foobar.real` without remaining in memory.